# Transform Set to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to convert a set of categories into a DataFrame?

For example:

```
A = [{'a', 'c'}, {'a', 'b'}, {'b', 'd'}, {'e'}]
```

To:

```
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'
1    1 ,  0 ,  1 ,  0 ,  0 
2    1 ,  1 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 
3    0 ,  1 ,  0 ,  1 ,  0 
4    0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  1
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's try `explode` then `crosstab`:

```
s = pd.Series(A).explode()
pd.crosstab(s.index, s)
```

Output:

```
col_0  a  b  c  d  e
row_0               
0      1  0  1  0  0
1      1  1  0  0  0
2      0  1  0  1  0
3      0  0  0  0  1
```

---

**Option 2**: `get_dummies` on the `explode`:

```
pd.get_dummies(pd.Series(A).explode()).sum(level=0)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  0  1  0  0
1  1  1  0  0  0
2  0  1  0  1  0
3  0  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the individual entries into a string, convert to a Series type, then apply [str.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) to get the result:

```
pd.Series(["|".join(entry) for entry in A]).str.get_dummies()

    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   0   1   0   0
1   1   1   0   0   0
2   0   1   0   1   0
3   0   0   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(A), prefix = ['', ''])
       .groupby(lambda x: x.strip(r'\_'), axis = 1)
       .sum()
```

Result is

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  0  1  0  0
1  1  1  0  0  0
2  0  1  0  1  0
3  0  0  0  0  1
```